# Highcharts Tooltip - Returns unwanted empty string causing render problems

Tags: highcharts

**custom tooltip.formatter** with (**useHTML: true**) correctly prints a series of span tags with the correct data, but for each point the browser renders an empty string "", which on some older chrome browsers contain a random symbol (**not point.symbol**). How do I get rid of this?

**Vue.js**

```
export default {
   methods: {
      leftSpan(text) {
         return "<span style='float: left;'>" + text + "</span>"
      },

      rightSpan(text) {
         return "<span style='float: right; font-weight: 600;'>" + text + "</span>"
      },

      tooltipFormatter(options) {
          const { total, x, points, that } = options

          let tooltip = "<span style='display: inline-block; width: 125px;'>"

          tooltip += "<span style='font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px; display: inline-block;'>" + x + "</span><br/>"

          points.forEach(point => {
                // EMPTY STRING IS BEING AUTOMATICLY IMPLEMENTED HERE
                tooltip += "<span style='display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 2px; width: 125px;'>"
                tooltip += this.leftSpan(this.translate(point.series.name) + ':') + this.rightSpan(point.y)
                tooltip += "</span><br/>"
          })

          tooltip += "</span>"

          return tooltip
      },
   }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Issue visible in CodeSandbox**
https://yvxp3r1wv1.codesandbox.io/

[image]

Comment: Hi @Abarth, I tested your code - http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rf84wb6g/ and it seems that an empty string is not generated. Could you reproduce your problem in some online code editor?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, thanks for looking in to this, I will link a version later today.

Comment: @ppotaczek https://yvxp3r1wv1.codesandbox.io/

Comment: Hi @Abarth, Thanks for the example. It seems that using `<br>` instead of `<br/>` solves the problem.

Comment: @ppotaczek While I wouldn't be surprised it could be the case, it makes no difference in my browser at least, both ```<br>``` and ```<br/>``` adds the following: ""

Comment: Ok, you have some unvisible marker at the beginning of the string in `leftSpan` function: `"<span style='float: left;'>" + text + "</span>";` Corrected example: https://codesandbox.io/s/842qo5xmp8

Comment: That's the answer right there, thank you mate ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some unvisible marker at the beginning of the string in `leftSpan` function:

```
"<span style='float: left;'>" + text + "</span>";
```

**Live example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/842qo5xmp8